# Using an arrow as a superscript on a variable

Tags: output-formatting, notation

I am trying to use an up and down arrow as part of my variable's name.

```
Subsuperscript[P, 2, "\[UpArrow]"]
```

Seems to almost do what I want, but it includes some really ugly quote marks around the arrow, but when I remove them it tries to treat the arrow as an operator.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any quote marks when I enter your input. What did you do that caused quote marks to show up?

Comment: Use `Format[P2] = TraditionalForm[Subsuperscript[P, 2, "\[UpArrow]"]]` then the variable `P2` will be displayed in the formatted form.